# Python Tk - Dynamically change button, defined in function, on click

Tags: python, button, click, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am new to making GUIs with Python and what I am trying to do should be pretty simple. Essentially, I have a dialog class that I use to instantiate a dialog in my program.  One of the things on this dialog is a button that I want to use to change color. I want the user to be able to click the button, be taken to a color chooser, then return to the dialog with the button changing to the color that was chosen.  In my dialog class, here is where I define the button.

```
def body(self, master):

  Label(master, text="Track URL:").grid(row=0)
  Label(master, text="Short label:").grid(row=1)
  Label(master, text="Long label:").grid(row=2)
  b = Button(master, text="Color",bg="white",command=self.chooseColor).grid(row=3)

  self.e1 = Entry(master)
  self.e2 = Entry(master)
  self.e3 = Entry(master)

  self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
  self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
  self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

  return self.e1 # initial focus
```

Then I just want a simple function to choose the color

```
   def chooseColor(self):
   color = askColor()
   b["bg"] = color
```

I understand that b is now out of scope, so I can't change it, but I don't understand how to get the color chosen in a place where I can change the button color.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `b` a member variable:

```
self.b = Button(.....)
```

Then `self.chooseColor` can "see" `self.b` and make changes to it:

```
def chooseColor(self):
    color = askColor()
    self.b["bg"] = color # or however you change a color in python/tkinter
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!